# Using two different mesh with curve/array modifiers in one nurbs curve?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I am trying to create a road network with different meshes.

What I want to do is to change the mesh of those inside the red box in the image below to a different mesh(like bridge). Any ideas how to do this? I was thinking of splitting the nurbs curve into two and make 2 meshes using the 2 splitted and separated mesh. But it won't connect properly since its using 2 curves.

[image]

What I want is something like this
[image]

Comment: You could probably have multiple smaller segments of road array, instead of one continuous one, maintaining the curve modifier, and manually move them along the Y axis. Then have multiple separate bridge segments and do the same, while maintaining an untouched continuous curve.